# Force round step in input type number with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, input, rounding

In a web app (AngualrJS 1.5 + HTML5) I have an input type="number". I want to step in 0.5. The problem is that if the user write 0.7, the form doesn't notificate the error. How can I do to automatic round the number in the field?

This is the html code:

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="height" name="height" min="1" max="10000" step="0.5">
```

I've tried to add this js code when I save the page:

```
$scope.age = (Math.round($scope.age * 2) / 2).toFixed(1);
```

but I get this error in console:

```
angular.js?v=0.2:13708 Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `6.0` to be a number
```

UPDATE:
I've made a plunker: [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/MYyJSYiw3qAXASNCXJ1F?p=preview)

Comment: jsFiddle or something like that?

Comment: Looks like you are assigning String to model,but it should be  number.Try parseFloat(yourmodel)

Comment: I've made a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into below code.

```
<body ng-app="numberExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('numberExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.age = 5;
      $scope.roundNo = function(){
        $scope.age = (Math.round($scope.age * 2) / 2);
      };
      $scope.save = function(){
      }
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="age"
           min="0" max="1000" step="0.5" ng-change="roundNo()" required>

 </form>
 <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</body>
```

Working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/WocmCbWQKgYV1vi4qdi0?p=preview)